# Discord.py: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0 )

Tags: python, discord.py

I have absolutely no idea whatsoever what this error means. I Googled it to no end and have spent five days just on this error. Please help. It's for a Discord bot that keeps an XP system in Python, and stores the info for players in a `.json` file.

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "JahBot.py", line 208, in on_message
    users = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I will put my currency code here:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r+') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        users = json.dump(users, f)
        
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('users.json', 'r+') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)
    
    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        users = json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        user[user.id]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await client.send_message(channel, '{} has leveled up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end
```

Comment: Is `users.json` empty, or start with whitespace?

Comment: It is completely empty

Comment: An empty file is not valid json.  Make it an empty mapping `{}`

Comment: How would i go about doing that? I have never worked with jsons before. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Open the file and type those characters into it.  JSON files are just text files.

Answer (score 0):

in the json file you need to put

```
{

}
```

when i found it out myself i felt so dumb